# How to setup Nginx and PHP-FPM socket

Tags: php, sockets, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have taken over managing the company's web hosting, which is an AWS server running Amazons own version of Linux and Nginx.

I don't have much experience of Nginx, but I need to create a subdomain running a development version of the site. There is already an existing "Staging" virtual host, however it is linked to the main sites database making useless.

I have copied the staging conf file from **/etc/nginx/conf.d/staging.conf** to **/etc/nginx/conf.d/dev.conf** and changed all instances of "staging" within the file to "dev".

This is what the file looks like:

```
upstream php-dev-backend {
    server unix:/tmp/php-fpm-dev.sock weight=1;
}

server {
    server_name dev.groundlevel.co.uk;
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/vhosts/dev.groundlevel.co.uk/web-root;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev.groundlevel.co.uk_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/dev.groundlevel.co.uk_error_log;
    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }
location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }

include magento_security;

include fastcgi_params;
location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
             rewrite / /index.php last;
        }
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php-dev-backend;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

However this is leading to a 502 error as /tmp/php-fpm-dev.sock doesn't exist and I have no Idea how to create it. Or if I can change the conf file to not need the socket.

Could someone please explain how to get the socket running? Thanks!

Comment: try this `touch  /tmp/php-fpm-dev.sock` and give permissions to nginx `sudo chown nginx:nginx  /tmp/php-fpm-dev.sock`

Comment: Since this isn't related to development, it's off topic for SO.  I'd recommend hiring a server administrator.  Even if you get this working, what's going to happen when something breaks?  Not smart to run a production web server without someone* experienced available to setup, secure, and maintain the system.

Comment: @devon I was worried about that, I originally posted to Super User but didn't get any responses. I have seen a few nginx related questions so I thought it would be okay to post here instead.

Comment: Super User is for personal computing, not servers.  Server Fault is the site for server administration.

Comment: @YamenNassif That has added to the tmp file but it still not working, in the shell the other sockets are showing in pink text, whereas this is in black.

Comment: There is no need for you to create a new socket. So don't change `server unix:/tmp/php-fpm-staging.sock weight=1;` Keep it as it is and all should work

Answer (score 1):

The /tmp/php-fpm-dev.sock socket should be created whenever the PHP-FPM service starts - if it is configured to listen at this socket.

If php-fpm is already running on this server for the 'staging' site, then it's possible that you could just re-use that socket.  FPM is running as a single instance, so there's really no need to run a separate socket unless you require a different configuration between 'dev' and 'staging'.

Is the 'staging' site working correctly?
If so, what fpm socket is it connecting to in /etc/nginx/conf.d/staging.conf?

You may also want to post the relevant socket configuration from your PHP-FPM config.  It should in somewhere in /etc/php???
Specifically what you're looking for is what sockets does FPM open up when it starts:

```
 [DOMAINNAME]

 listen = /var/run/php5-fpm/DOMAINNAME.socket <-- socket being opened
 listen.backlog = -1
 listen.owner = nginx
 listen.group = www-data
 listen.mode=0660
```

Comment: PHP-FPM is already running and I did try restarting it to see if it would help, but the socket did not get created. The staging one does work and uses the socket php-fpm-staging.sock. I don't have an /etc/php folder, and I can find at least four different php-fpm.conf files in different directories, none contain the information you've shown. How could I reuse the existing socket, I'm hesitant as I don't want to risk any problems with the live site.

Comment: You can re-use the same socket by just specifying it in your dev.conf instead of the dev socket. So, in your **/etc/nginx/conf.d/dev.conf**, just use **php-fpm-staging.sock** instead of **php-fpm-dev.sock**    The socket is just where fpm is listening for connections for a given configuration profile.  If you can use the same (php-fpm) configuration for dev and staging, then re-using the same socket should be fine.

Comment: I do understand you wanting to keep them separate though.  In the four different php-fpm.conf files you found there's no line in any of them with 'php-fpm-staging.sock'?  .. Try using grep to make sure:  grep "php-fpm-staging.sock" <conf_file>  If you can find the conf file that specifies using that socket, you can copy and change it to also open up the dev socket

Comment: No there's no lines relating to it in any of them. I've got /etc/php-fpm.conf, /etc/php-fpm-5.5.conf, /etc/php-fpm.d/php-fpm.conf, and /etc/php-fpm-5.5.d/php-fpm.conf. They're all identical and the only non commented out lines are for include other conf files, pid and error log

Comment: If fpm is creating the php-fpm-staging.sock socket, then it should be in a config file somewhere.  Try tracing through those included files.  If they're all in /etc, then you could run a recursive grep to search.... <from /etc> grep "php-fpm-staging.sock" * -irn  ... at the end of the day, you'll need to create a php-fpm config file if you want to open up a separate dev socket.  If you're not able to do this, then sharing the staging socket may be your only other option.

Comment: I've just run the search and its only coming up in the nginx conf file. I've changed to use the existing staging socket now so its a good enough workaround. There is a staging.conf file which has: listen = /tmp/php-fpm-$pool.sock, so I think that must be it. I assume $pool is a variable, I just need to find where it is getting it from

Comment: Yeah, I think you're on the right track now.  Look in the directories you mentioned earlier (/etc/php-fpm.d and /etc/php-fpm-5.5.d) and there should be a directory somewhere in there for the pool config files.  If you can find the staging one, you should be able to copy & change the pool name and restart fpm to have it create the new dev socket.  -- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php - i'll be in this chat for a while if you need any more help